The first MySQL query is slower than the subsequent ones
The first MySQL query is slower than the subsequent ones. I am trying to achieve the same speed on the first query as on the subsequent ones.
I would like an explanation and a solution to this problem.
It must be some mysql caching thing. I tried to search for this topic, but didnt find what I expected.

After you've run the first query, everything that MySQL needed to read from the disk is now cached in memory by the operating system - this is a good thing. If you want to have the first query run as fast as everything afterwards, make the OS load the index into RAM first (or simply run the query once as your application setup so that everything that is necessary is available). Other optimizations techniques will depend on which engine you're using, etc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/9.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-optimization.html - monitor and look at what takes time (profiling).

To speed up your first MySQL query, please increase the buffer pool size or you can use query cache.

FWIW, the query cache feature was deprecated in MySQL 5.7 and removed from MySQL 8.0. See the note on this manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Both of your suggested tunings could lead to the second query being even faster, not slower.
